# Global array in golang

Tags: arrays, go, global-variables

I'm trying to declare a global array and then init it later like so:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)
var testStrings []string

func main() {
  testStrings = [...]string{"apple","banana","kiwi"}
  fmt.Println(testStrings)
}
```

But I'm getting error: "cannot use [3]string literal (type [3]string) as type []string in assignment"

How do I declare global array without specifying size?

Comment: Use a slice instead.

Comment: Also, for simple initialization it's more common to just do it in the global `var` statement rather than use an `init` function. E.g. `var testStrings = []string{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"}`.

Comment: @DaveC, I agree. I didn't mention it but actually, this is a stripped down version for a go test fixture with lazy init.

Comment: There's nothing "global" about your question or the answer(s) -- I recommend editing your question to reflect that. I would change the title to focus more on the error you found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> The notation `...` specifies an array length equal to the maximum element index plus one.

This does not work for your code because `testStrings` is a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), not an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) (read about [the difference between arrays and slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices)).  Dropping the `...` will fix your program:

```
testStrings = []string{"apple","banana","kiwi"}
```

Answer (score 10):

`[...]` means an [array](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays).

`[]` means a [slice](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).

Change one. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var arrtestStrings [3]string
var slicetestStrings []string

func main() {
    arrtestStrings = [...]string{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"}
    slicetestStrings = []string{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"}
    fmt.Println(arrtestStrings)
    fmt.Println(slicetestStrings)
}
```